# two where clause in single linq query

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table memberaccounts

```
              member_id
              member_name
              membertransactionamount
              memberaccount_id
```

and my entity name is databasecontextsearch

and i am binding these details to datagrid view by using foolwing way

```
        var memberdetails = from members in databasecontextsearch.memberacconuts
                              select new 
                               {  
                                  memberid = members.member_id
                                  name = members.member_name
                                  amount = members.membertransactionamount
                                 };
                         bindingsource1.datasource = memberdetails;
                        datagridview1.datasource = bindingsource1;
```

and i have a text box (txtsrch) and a button (search)

when ever the user enter the member_name in text box(txtsrch) the the member details will be populated with datagrid view according to that member_name..

when ever  the user enter the membertransactionamount in the textbox(txtsrch) datagrid view will be populated with member  details those who have that membertransactionamount..

is it possible these conditions in single if condition using linq to entities...

Comment: The answer is yes. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: i havenot tried any thing i am looking for any ideas...

Comment: there's nothing special here simply add a where and put '&&' between the two boolean statements

Comment: why r u guys giving downvote ...if you know just suggest me any ideas .....

Comment: Because we are here to help you figure out things you can't do by yourself. It looks like you didn't even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "transform" this into an AND:

```
var memberdetails = from members in databasecontextsearch.memberacconuts
                    where 
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(name_param)?true:members.memebername==name_param
                    &&
                    ((tran_param!=null?members.membertransactionamount==tran_param:true))
                    select new 
                    {  
                         memberid = members.member_id
                         name = members.member_name
                         amount = members.membertransactionamount
                    };
```

Explanation:

If name_param is null or empty, the first part of the where condition will evaluate to true; if not, will do the comparison.

If the tran_param is null, the second part of the where will evaluate to true; if not, will do the comparison with membertransactionmaount.

Comment: @lcarus I have a small doubt where do i enter the txtsrch.text values in this query....

Comment: can i replace nam_param with txtsrch.text values

Comment: @user852714 correct, the nam_param should be replaced by your txtsrc.txt value and the tran_param by whatever text field you use to capture the amount